# Speech_Recognition connection failed and prints this error

Tags: python, flask, speech-recognition

I use this code for Transcriber, everything works perfectly well, but when I try to read a file that is longer than 2min, script prints this error.

It tries to read the audio file for a very long time and only then prints the error.

I searched on the net but could not find the right answer.

Please your help, thanks!

**Python** /root/app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import speech_recognition as sr

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    transcript = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("FORM DATA RECEIVED")

        if "file" not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename == "":
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file:
            recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
            audioFile = sr.AudioFile(file)
            with audioFile as source:
                data = recognizer.record(source)
            transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, key=None)

    return render_template('index.html', transcript=transcript)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

**HTML** /templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Speech Recognition</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/index.css') }}" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="speechContainer">
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Transcribe"/>
    </form>

    {% if transcript != "" %}
        <div id="speechTranscriptContainer">
            <h1>Transcript</h1>
            <p id="speechText">{{ transcript }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PROBLEM!!!**

```
speech_recognition.RequestError
speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition connection failed: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1049, in _send_output
self.send(chunk)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 971, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 840, in recognize_google
response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1375, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "/Users/edukom/Desktop/Projects-master/Speech-Recognition-Python-Final/app.py", line 59, in index
transcript = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language=language)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 844, in recognize_google
raise RequestError("recognition connection failed: {}".format(e.reason))
speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition connection failed: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Comment: I see you get file from `form` - did you try to save it on disk and open in any audio player or check it in other tools if it send correct data? Some server may have restriction for data size and you may get incomplete data. And some server may has restricion how long can run code - ie. 30 seconds - to prevernt [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_attack) attack. And then code should run in separated thread or using `Celery` - and client/browser should get unique ID which later it can use to check if result is ready (and often it need JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. The file is not stored on the hard disk and can you show by example how to overcome this problem, please and thank you!

Comment: I don't know what is real problem so I can't show solution First you should check if `data`/`file` is correct. If data is wrong then it may need different solution than if data is correct.

Comment: I have published the complete code of this project, you can look in my post, if you can, please help me, thank you !!!

Comment: I don't have 2min file to test it :) But [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas) for Google Speech shows that there can be limit `~1min` and `10 MB`. You may need different module for this. ie. [Python Client for Cloud Speech API](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech) (and [example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/samples/snippets/transcribe_async.py)) but it may need also to upload file to Google Storage.

Comment: Google Could doc: [Transcribing long audio files](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize)